# How to combine two graphs in R?

Tags: r

I have a histogram and a curve and want to draw them on a single chart. how can i do this?

```
hist(rexp(n, 3))
curve(dnorm, from=0, to=1, n)
```

Comment: Just add `add=TRUE` to your curve statement

Comment: You might want to add the argument `prob=TRUE` to your `hist` function aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Add curve 'add=TRUE'.

```
hist(rexp(n, 3))
curve(dnorm, from=0, to=1, n,add=TRUE)
```